# How to pass param file when applying a new yaml

Tags: openshift, openshift-4

I am on on openshift 4.6. I want to pass parameters when to a yaml file so i tried the below code but it threw an error

```
oc apply -f "./ETCD Backup/etcd_backup_cronjob.yaml" --param master-node = oc get nodes -o name |  grep "master-0" | cut -d'/' -f2
```

Error: unknown flag --param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you most likely want to use is [OpenShift Templates](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/openshift_images/using-templates.html#templates-writing-parameters_using-templates). Using Templates you can have variables in your YAML files and then change them using `oc process`.

So your YAML would look like so:

```
kind: Template
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-template
objects:
  - apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
    kind: CronJob
    metadata:
      name: pi
    spec:
      schedule: "*/1 * * * *"  
      concurrencyPolicy: "Replace" 
      startingDeadlineSeconds: 200 
      suspend: true            
      successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3 
      failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1     
      jobTemplate:             
        spec:
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:          
                 parent: "cronjobpi"
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: pi
                image: perl
                command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(${{DIGITS}})"]
              restartPolicy: OnFailure 
parameters:
  - name: DIGITS 
    displayName: Number of digits 
    description: Digits to compute
    value: 200 
    required: true
```

Then you can use `oc process` like so:

```
oc process my-template.yml --param=DIGITS=300 | oc apply -f -
```